# Parsed my .obj file but it is being displayed weirdly

Tags: c++, opengl, .obj

I followed a tutorial of how to create a castle in blender, I then exported as a .obj file and parsed it to a format that looks as follows:

```
GLfloat mesh01_coords[] = {
50, 0.1, 50,
-50, 0.1, 50,
-50, 0.1, -50,
50, 0.1, -50,
-9.6351, 9.94983, 17.4283,
-9.6351, 9.94983, 18.7616,
-9.07887, 9.94983, 18.7616,
-9.07887, 9.94983, 17.4283,
10.2729, 9.94983, 18.8564,
10.2729, 9.94983, 17.523,
9.71662, 9.94983, 17.523,
9.71662, 9.94983, 18.8564,
10.3075, 9.94983, 20.0883,
8.97417, 9.94983, 20.0883,
8.97417, 10.9498, 20.0883,
...
```

EDIT: I have my index array set up

```
GLubyte mesh01_indices[] = {
0, 2, 1,
0, 3, 2,
4, 6, 5,
4, 7, 6,
...
```

Wouldn't my model load just be

```
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, mesh01_normals);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, mesh01_coords);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, n, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mesh01_indices);
```

This produces random objects nothing close to my desired result

EDIT2: Thank you everyone for the help, I got it working.

Comment: You are using the indices as well? Those are what define the triangles. The coordinates are merely the vertices of your mesh.

Comment: My question is if i should be using GL_QUADS or not as well as could the problem be that my array is roughly 20000 indices long? What would be the work-a-round for this?

Comment: If i use `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mesh01_indices);` I cannot see anything

Comment: Could you explain how you got it working so that others may benefit from your knowledge? Post it as a new answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Obj files use indices. Basically what this means is that you eliminate repeating vertices by specifying triangles as indexes into your vertex array, instead of specifying triangles with vertices directly.

Here is an example of the "naive" way of doing things for drawing a square (pseudocode):

```
// Triangle 1
Vertex v1 = (-1, 1, 0)
Vertex v2 = (-1, -1, 0)
Vertex v3 = (1, -1, 0)
// Triangle 2
Vertex v4 = (1, -1, 0)
Vertex v5 = (-1, 1, 0)
Vertex v6 = (1, 1, 0)
```

Using indices this would look like:

```
Vertex v1 = (-1, 1, 0)
Vertex v2 = (-1, -1, 0)
Vertex v3 = (1, -1, 0)
Vertex v4 = (1, 1, 0)

indices = {v1, v2, v3, // First triangle
          v3, v1, v4}  // Second triangle
```

Now since you are loading your data the "naive" way, you are basically skipping some triangles that would need to be rendered (hence the "missing aspects"). Also, some triangles will not render correctly since you are creating them from vertices which might have no relation to one another.

Using GL_QUADS will not solve your problem. You can either create an index buffer which operates like in the second example, or store the vertices, and then loop through the indices and create individual vertices from the index into the vertex array, which would result in something similar to the first example. However, doing it the latter way will result in poorer performance and more memory consumption, since you are storing more vertices, and hence need to pass more information to the graphics card.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @NickLH, I edited my main post with my index array but still unable to get a result

Answer (score 1):

By using GL_UNSIGNED_INT for my indices, as well as re-compiling my blender file to assure everything was indeed triangles I was able to see the castle

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mesh01_indices);
```

will draw only one triangle as it will use only the first 3 indices. Try

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, n, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mesh01_indices);
```

where n is the number of indices in `mesh01_indices`.

Comment: Thank you for that, my result does show a bit more per say. Although its nothing remotely close to my desired result. Almost just looks like random primitives.

Comment: Could you try changing your `GLubyte mesh01_indices[]` to `GLuint mesh01_indices[]` and subsequently use GL_UNSIGNED_INT instead of GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE?

Comment: I am now getting somewhat look of a castle, but many things missing. Im starting to think my blender didnt export properly or something